# Why do the camera and the character not move when I use my own mapping context?

Tags: unreal, blueprints, unreal-5

I replaced the defult mannequin with my character and created a new input action and an input mapping context.

[image]

[image]

But when I change the default mapping context to mine, the camera and the character never move, and I can’t move the character using the buttons, nor can the camera move like before when I move my mouse.

[image]

Why do the camera and the character not move when I use my own mapping context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way the question is asked, it occurs to me that you are assuming that defining the action will automatically make your Character pick them up. You still need to listen to the action somewhere, e.g. in the Player Controller and translate it into a movement, e.g. like so (my Action name is obviously different from yours):

[image: Blueprint listening to the defined action]